# Convert object in clipboard to base64

Tags: c#, base64

i have in clipboard OBJECT(for example example1.jpg) and i need convert this object to base 64, It is possible? I have own wysiwyg editor, and when i paste the file with image i need to convert him to base 64.

in this i have the object:

```
object objekt = Clipboard.GetDataObject();
```

Comment: Objects on the clipboard can be in many formats.  If it is JPEG file then you ought to use Clipboard.GetImage().  What you do with the returned Image object is up to grabs, you can save it to a MemoryStream with Image.Save() and encode it do base64 with Convert.ToBase64String().

Comment: @Hans Passant: and when is the format png or gif?

Comment: The Image class does not care.  The image format is a file property, not an object property.

Comment: When i have jpeg file in clipboard and i have this: Image jpegimage=Clipboard.GetImage(); the jpegimage is null...

Comment: Then you don't have an image on the clipboard.  I cannot possibly guess what you do have.  Use Clipboard.GetDataObject().GetFormats() to give us a clue.

Comment: Clipboard.GetDataObject().GetFormats(); :{string[10]}string[]   I copy the file image1.jpg on desktop in windows (if i try ctrl+V i have image)...